# liferay message board with nickname

Tags: liferay

we want to use liferays message board in our portal. but instead of storing and displaying the name of the user with all messages we need a separate nickname to be stored and diplayed within the message board.

the storing of nickname is done already: by creating a custom field "nickname" for user and overriding/reimplementing of "MBMessageLocalServiceImpl.addMessage" within an ext-plugin.

Now every message stores the nickname of the user as "username" in message table. But as you probably already know the stored nickname isn't displayed along with the message because all user displaying stuff get the user data via the user id and the "username" within message is never displayed or even used.
now i began to dig into liferay source to find where the user displaying is done: "html/taglib/uiuserDisplay/start.jsp". But i guess if fiddle around with this i will change more than the user display in message board?!

So what is the least invasive/easiest to get a message board with a distinct "nickname".

Comment: You can use a "JSP Hook" to "overwrite" the JSP page that Liferay uses without the need to change the source code. Search the Liferay wiki for "JSP hook" for examples and more details.

Comment: meanwhile i have jsp-hook for "../user_display/start.jsp" but as mentioned in the question this overrides all places (e.g. blog) where user_display is used. and on the other hand it overrrides not all places within message board where user name is displayed (e.g. in table with all threads "started by" and "last post" still displays the user name). I need to display the nickname within message board. Could you probably provide a list with all jsps to be modified?

Comment: I would only modify only the JSP pages used in the message board. Probably by **not** including `user_display/start.jsp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I can think of is with a hook.

You would need to find all the places in MessageBoard portlet's jsp i.e. `/html/portlet/message_boards/` where the name of the User is displayed and use your nickname instead.

And you can also modify `/html/taglib/uiuserDisplay/start.jsp` conditionally, i.e. you can check in this `start.jsp` through `themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getPortletName()` if this is the message_boards portlet (portletId = `19`) and then include your custom code to display nick-name or else it would be normal flow.

Might be tedious but then this is a liferay portlet you are modifying :-)

Comment: thx - i began to hunt down all sites where user name is used/displayed and modified start.jsp but for now i don't need to do it conditionally because the blog isn't used at the moment.